# ImportError: No module named 'pystan'on MacOS

Tags: python-module, pystan

I installed `pystan` on a python virtual environment using `pip install pystan`. I checked the module is listed with pip freeze.  but when i run a code with `import pystan`. It gives the error that the module is not found.

below is the output from pip freeze command. It shows pystan version 3.3.0

```
aiohttp==3.7.4.post0
appdirs==1.4.4
async-timeout==3.0.1
attrs==21.2.0
chardet==4.0.0
clikit==0.6.2
crashtest==0.3.1
httpstan==4.6.0
idna==3.2
lz4==3.1.3
marshmallow==3.13.0
multidict==5.2.0
numpy==1.21.2
pandas==1.3.3
pastel==0.2.1
pylev==1.4.0
pysimdjson==3.2.0
pystan==3.3.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
six==1.16.0
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
webargs==8.0.1
yarl==1.7.0
```

however when i try to import the module from console it throws the below error.

```
import pystan
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pystan'
```

importing any other module listed is not throwing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution at this [link](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/pystan-import-error-in-a-seemingly-successful-installation/23463)

> Apparently the most recent versions of pystan (>= 3) use stan instead
> of pystan in the import statement, whereas in earlier versions it was
> just pystan.

if you install pystan (>=3) use `import stan` instead of `import pystan`